# How to insert a \part section in a R Markdown file?

Tags: parts, markdown

I'm not sure that it's the right place to post it, but, after all, it is especially about Latex too. This is my question: I've been trying to figure out how to use R Markdown with Latex. Indeed, I need to simplify my workflow in order to output articles both for PDF and... Word. Using RStudio works very well for that task, but I can't get \part in my file, even when I insert a documentclass: book in my YAML preamble and I did not find anything on the web to help me. Does anyone know how to do it? This is my YAML preamble:

```
---
title: A title
documentclass: book
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
    number_sections: yes
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
date: 9 juillet 2022
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: "left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm"
linestretch: 1.5
header-includes:
  - \usepackage [french]{babel}
---
```

Comment: (The correct way to format code is ``​`​`​`​``, not `---`. Always check the preview pane to see if the question looks correct before posting.)

Comment: Not sure if it's solvable. Surely you can use inline LaTeX, but then Word output will probably break.

Comment: @user202729 The `---` were actually part of the rmarkdown code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latex `\part` macro in your rmarkdown body:

```
---
title: A title
documentclass: book
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
    number_sections: yes
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
date: 9 juillet 2022
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: "left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm"
linestretch: 1.5
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[french]{babel}
---

test

\part{A new Part}

test
```

[image]